# Как в Notepad++ найти нужную строку и в этой строке заменить один фрагмент. С помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: регулярные-выражения

В текстовом документе: Найти --- ввожу `(.*)\:ТЕХНО 24` Далее нажимаю: Найти в текущем документе.
Нахожу две строки:

```
#SERVICE 4097:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:http%3a//ott-cdn.ucom.am/s68/index.m3u8:Техно 24
#SERVICE 4097:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:http%3a//109.171.58.141%3a81/udp/239.54.7.56%3a1224:ТЕХНО 24
```

Всё правильно. В другом поиске найденных строк может быть и 2 и более.

---

Как в этих найденных двух или более строках заменить часть строки: `4097:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0` нужно заменить на `4097:0:1:7D3:2:FD:1680000:0:0:0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(^.*)4097:0:1:0:0:0:0:0:0:0(.*:ТЕХНО 24\s*$)
```

заменить на

```
$14097:0:1:7D3:2:FD:1680000:0:0:0$2
```